# Running php files from SmartFtp through an apache server

Tags: php, apache

I am currently working alongside a project team for the development of a website and we are using SmartFtp for file sharing.

Does anyone know how to compile/edit php files through SmartFtp? I.e. using apache for compiling and atom for editing.

Please note: I have already tried copying the files into the htdocs folder within xampp but had no luck. The php files did not successfully copy into the htdocs folder.

Thanks again

Comment: Are you using folder syncing with SmartFtp?

Comment: I think so but tonight was the first time I had ever used SmartFtp.

Comment: _"we are using SmartFtp for file sharing"_ Egad man, switch to git before it's too late. :)

Comment: I am using git for everything else and I prefer git. Unfortunately I am not the project manager and this project was set up with a basic Ftp server. Is it possible to log onto a Ftp server using git? i.e. import files from server to a brand new git repo.

Comment: I'm confused -- is this a live server that you simply want to deploy completed edits to? Or a dev server that multiple people are "sharing" by FTP pushing edits ad hoc while they code?

Comment: Development sever with multiple people pushing edits ad hoc while they code through an Ftp server. Sorry for the confusion - I have only been introduced to this technology for the first time tonight, so I don't really know what I am talking about.

Comment: Everybody pushing to one common directory? Or each user has their own?

Comment: One common directory. There is only two people working on this and we are working on different areas of the webpage so, it is pretty hard for code to clash.

Answer (score 1):

Fair warning...

This is a **terrible** way to host a project. Each developer should have their own isolated project installation. Even though you only have a few developers, it's only a matter of time before you get a collision and somebody loses work.

Using FTP is also a **terrible** idea. It is completely insecure.

That said, you've got a couple options:

- If your dev server is a *nix flavor, you can probably use SSHFS to mount the remote directory on your local machine. This will allow you to edit the remote files live, as if they were any other regular local file. This is secure and relatively easy to set up, but you may find it a bit too slow for anything but small projects.
- Use FTPS/SFTP/SCP to push files to the remote server when you save them locally. I'm not terribly familiar with Atom, but many IDEs (like NetBeans and PHPStorm) can be configured to automatically FTPS/SFTP/SCP push changed files to remote servers. Just save locally as you normally would, and in the background, the IDE will perform an FTPS/SFTP/SCP push. Do **not** use FTP. If your server has FTP configured, it probably also has SFTP and/or FTPS configured.
- Create your own development environment. Host your own site on your own machine so that you don't collide. You can run Apache/Nginx/PHP/MySQL directly on your machine, in a virtual box, or even a docker container. This is the best and most flexible option, but also requires the most effort to get running.

Comment: Does git support Ftp? I.e. copying all files into git repo. I am comfortable using git and prefer it.

Comment: No, but you could pretty easily set up a post commit hook to push the file. I wouldn't recommend that though, as it requires you to commit everything before testing it.

Comment: What's the best way of doing this from SmartFtp? I don't have a local copy of my files and cannot copy the system in full. It doesn't really matter if the system is untested as I have not yet added to it and simply want to transfer everything to git.

Comment: I don't know anything about SmartFtp, you should be able to use any FTP client.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment, but its a bit long.

I am really confused by your question.

> how to compile/edit php files

PHP uses a run-time compiler. Are you talking about Roadsend or HipHop or something else?

> development of a website and we are using SmartFtp for file sharing

Presumably you don't give a damn about your code integrity, managing conflicting code changes, version control or the security of your development environment. It's 2017. FTP was way past its sell-by date before the turn of the millenium.

> compile/edit php files through SmartFtp

It's an FTP client. Just one of many things you don't use to compile or edit files (others include an avacado, a tennis shoe, scissors, a sunset...).

Presumably you are using this client to connect to a server - which you've told us nothing about. You probably want to do the collaborative bit of your code management (if that is what you are asking) on the server.

(from comments)

> Development sever with multiple people pushing edits ad hoc while they code through an Ftp server.

That's not a "development server" that's a recipe for code armageddon.

Comment: I understand that GitHub is better but I cannot change the file sharing method as I am not the project manager. Is there anyway of editing and compiling the groups php files with this FTP server. I know I have stressed this a few times but I am new to this so please keep it simple.

Comment: Also, my project manager has decided to use Joomla so that might be the reason for a Ftp server.

Comment: Using Joomla has **NOTHING** to with any reason for using FTP.